# Recently Added Articles Joomla 3.2

Tags: article, joomla3.2

Joomla 3.2 shows "Recently Added Articles" (last 5) at the Admin panel dashboard.
I want to show those recently added article from any category on front site as module.
Like:
Rencent added articles:
article 5
article 4
article 3
article 2
article 1

Is there any option to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new Module in the Module Manager. Use the default Latest Articles module that ships with Joomla 3.2. In the settings you can select the module position you want it to display in your template, what categories to pull articles from, how many articles to show, what pages to display the module on and many other options.

Comment: Is it possible to show the latest articles with an article blog in com_content? That is what I'm looking for.